# Woocommerce - Tax optional

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way for the customer to choose whether or not to include the tax in his order?

I imagine a field called "With / Without TAX"

And some code that based on that field, perform the necessary calculations.

If this is not possible, how could you add a button within the order edition to include or exclude taxes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by hooking into woocommerce_checkout_create_order when the order is placed. (Normal orders are taxed on customer's address, curbside orders are based on store address. You can simply use 0 based on if your customer checks a box)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', array( $this, 'curbside_order'), 10, 1);

public function curbside_order( $order ) {

    if( /** without tax - post_meta, checkbox or however you set it**/){      
        $order->set_cart_tax(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Do you think I can use the same approach in the backend, in the option to edit the order? So that an administrator can eliminate the tax?

Comment: Yes. I also used the woocommerce API to do something similar... it allows an employee to edit an order (including tax) from a point of sale system without logging into WC